# Unable to install latest gitlab-ce on Fedora 23

Tags: gitlab, fedora-23

To install Gitlab I am using the instructions in the following link,

https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/el/6/gitlab-ce-8.6.6-ce.0.el6.x86_64.rpm

Executing the following command

`curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash`

results in following output.

```
The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
```

Later executing the following command

`[x@localhost ~]$ sudo dnf install gitlab-ce-8.6.6-ce.0.el6.x86_64`

results in the follwing output,

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:59:58 ago on Mon Apr 18 23:11:56 2016.
No package gitlab-ce-8.6.6-ce.0.el6.x86_64 available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

Please provide a solutiion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitLab doesn't provide native installation packages for Fedora [at this time](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14043), so you have to install from source.

GitLab does provide a [detailed guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) on how to install from source, but it's for Ubuntu. You'll have to translate it into Fedora yourself.